# How to execute json decode in live server?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, json

I am currently working in google map API.In google map API, i am fetching longitude and latitude from specific address.

Here is the code:

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1746+Esterbrook+Dr&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

In this latitude and longitude the values are shown as empty(null) in my live server.In my localhost machine, its working perfectly fine. Is any thing to include for display google map?

Comment: First check on your server what you get in `$geocode`, try `echo $geocode;` before `$output= json_decode($geocode);`

Comment: Make sure you have `allow_url_fopen` to on. I suspect you have error reporting off so you are not being told the URL is not being fetched and that the vars are being set to NULL.

Comment: then var_dump($output); to check that the json is decoding correctly into an array and you're referencing the correct information personally I always use the XML feeds from google rather than json feeds as the xml requires alot less processing to handle I feel

Comment: It's almost always a config issue when switching from dev to live.

Comment: thank @RohanKumar for ur responsive comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer returning arrays as its less ambiguous.  You do this by setting the second parameter to true on the json decode.  Also I would recommend assuming that its not always going to return results thats why I have added extra if statements.Follow this URL..

[PHP.net function json-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1746+Esterbrook+Dr&sensor=false');


if(strlen($geocode)>0){

  $output= json_decode($geocode, true);

  if(is_array($output) && count($output)>0)
  {
    $output[0]['location']['lat']  ;
    print_r($output); // the printr will give you a clue for the exact nesting to use above
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Robbo_UK thank for ur valuable answer...its working perfectly..but in my hosting server, its can`t display properly...is any other solution for this? else how to enable j son decoder in live server? please clarify it .........

Comment: Does the print_r return results?  it should output a list of items.  Have you tried outputting the $geocode to see if the file_get_contents returns results?